# VHDL weird behavoir of an array of unsigneds

Tags: arrays, vhdl

basically I have a array of unsigneds and a process that increments the first value of in the array by one. This worked fine untill I implemented an asynchronos reset, that sets the elements of the array to 0. The weird thing is, even when the code of the asynchronos reset is never reached, it makes the rest of my code not work anymore. Here is my code:

```
use work.datentyp.all;

library IEEE;
    use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
    use IEEE.numeric_std.all;
entity vektoruhr is
    port (

        clk, reset : in std_logic ;
    );
end vektoruhr;
architecture v1 of vektoruhr is

    signal internal_stamp : vektor := (others => (others => '0'));

begin

process(clk)
    begin
        if(rising_edge(clk)) then
            internal_stamp(0) <= internal_stamp(0) + 1;
        end if;
    end process;

    process(reset)
    begin
    if(rising_edge(reset)) then
        report "reset triggered"; 
        -- internal_stamp <= (others => (others => '0'));
        alarm <= '0';
    end if;
    end process;
end v1;
```

As you can see, the line

```
 -- internal_stamp <= (others => (others => '0'));
```

is commented out. Like this, everything works fine. But if I delete the --, the value of the first element is 00 first, then gets changed to 0x after the first incrementation and to xx after the second one. After that it stay at xx. The reset input is set to '0' from the begining and is never changed.

Comment: Had you posted all this code when you first asked your question, we could have answered it much more quickly.

Comment: The code doesn't analyze. there's an extraneous semicolon (a declaration separator after the port interface object declaration before the closing ')' in the port  declaration. No type declaration for vektor (presumably in missing package `datentyp`). The signal assignment target `alarm` is not declared (and not necessary to the question).  Not quite an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but sufficient to show multiple drivers.  See IEEE Std 1076-2008 14.7.2 Drivers "Every signal assignment statement in a process statement defines a set of drivers for certain scalar signals."

Comment: The source for package numeric_std ([-2008](http://standards.ieee.org/downloads/1076/1076-2008/), [earlier revisions](http://standards.ieee.org/downloads/1076/1076.2-1996/)) tells us type unsigned is a resolved signal subtype or type.  4.6 Resolution function para 3 "The resolution function associated with a resolved signal determines the resolved value of the signal as a function of the collection of inputs from its multiple sources." The resolution function `resolved` is found in package std_logic_1164.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VHDL is a hardware description language.  Each process represents a piece of hardware. You are driving the signal `internal_stamp` from two processes.; you have a short circuit.  When you comment out the line

```
 internal_stamp <= (others => (others => '0'));
```

this results in `internal_stamp` being driven from only one process. Hence no short circuit and no 'X' values.

If you're coding sequential logic, you should stick to a template. Here is one such template for sequential logic with an asynchronous reset, which all synthesis tools should understand:

```
process(clock, async_reset)  -- nothing else should go in the sensitivity list
begin
    -- never put anything here
    if async_reset ='1' then  -- or '0' for an active low reset
        -- set/reset the flip-flops here
        -- ie drive the signals to their initial values
    elsif rising_edge(clock) then  -- or falling_edge(clock)
        -- put the synchronous stuff here
        -- ie the stuff that happens on the rising or falling edge of the clock
    end if;
     -- never put anything here
end process;
```

Here is a template for sequential logic without an asynchronous reset:

```
process(clock)  -- nothing else should go in the sensitivity list
begin
    if rising_edge(clock) then  -- or falling_edge(clock)
        -- put the synchronous stuff here (including the reset)
        -- ie the stuff that happens on the rising or falling edge of the clock
    end if;
     -- never put anything here
end process;
```

So, you should code your logic using one process, not two. Assuming you want an *asynchronous reset*:

```
process(clk, reset)
    begin
        if reset = '1' then
          report "reset triggered"; 
          internal_stamp <= (others => (others => '0'));
          alarm <= '0';
        elsif(rising_edge(clk)) then
          internal_stamp(0) <= internal_stamp(0) + 1;
        end if;
    end process;
```

However, if you want a *synchronous reset*:

```
process(clk)
    begin
      if(rising_edge(clk)) then
        if reset = '1' then
          report "reset triggered"; 
          internal_stamp <= (others => (others => '0'));
          alarm <= '0';
        else
          internal_stamp(0) <= internal_stamp(0) + 1;
        end if;
    end process;
```